# Finding image for a node in Drupal

Tags: mysql, drupal

I have Drupal database and I am first time checking anything related to Drupal.

### Background:

I need to migrate data from Drupal database to a MS SQL database, not all data but specific to an entity like product/item.

The entity, which I need to migrate has some text fields like title, body etc. and a image field, image field is stored under file table which has id, path(url) field but not sure how this file table record link to main entity

### What I need:

How to find relation between main entity and file table record for image?

Answer (score 0):

I got the link in content_field_thumb table which has fid linked to file table as well as id of entity.